# How to map Dto to Entity and Entity to Dto in java

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a UserDto:

```
class UserDto{

   int id;

   String name;

   List<UserDto> users;
}
```

And I want this UserDto class map to UserEntity class:

```
class UserEntity{
    @id
    int id;
    
    int userId;

    @Column(name = "parent_id")
    int parentId;
    
    String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    List<UserEntity> users;
}
```

How to organize this correctly so that this sheet is created correctly?

Comment: What is the problem that you have ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DTO to Entity And Entity to DTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13899291/dto-to-entity-and-entity-to-dto)

Comment: No,  the problem is that I cannot map the List of same class ( List<UserDto> users to List<UserEntity>).

Answer (score 1):

If you trying to map properties from entity to dto or dto to entity , I recommend you make use of mapstruct dependency, with this utility you can create new interface and where you can define your own methods to map objets.

code for your reference..

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface UserMapper {
   UserEntity toUserEntity(UserDto UserDto);
   UserDto toUserDto(UserEntity userEntity);
   List<UserDto> toUserDtoList (List<UserEntity> UserEntityList);
}
```

This way, MapStruct automatically generates the code needed for the mapping based on your interface.
Don't forget to add the MapStruct dependency to your project's pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
        <version>${mapstruct-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I receive UnhandledException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Comment: replace ${mapstruct-version} with latest version